# Wep App Performance Improvement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a web application which is used for Assessments. I use PHP and MySQL on the server, jQuery on the client. The UI is such that there is a question followed by multiple choices( radios ). The user clicks buttons ( forward or back ) after selecting options from the radios. The app then submits the chosen option via ajax while the previous or next question is presented to the user. No feedback to the user is necessary.

Although this app will be used mostly on local intranet, some customers will use it on the Internet. I cannot upload a screen short because of my limited rep.

This is the ajax

```
$.ajax({ 

       type: 'POST',
       url: 'ajax.php',
       data: myData,
       dataType:'json',
       encode:true,
      })

      .done( function( response ){

         //the response from server is OK    
         if( response == "OK" ){   
           // Do something
         }
         //the response from server is BAD
         else if( response == 'BAD' ){

            // Do something else                     
         }
     })
     .fail( function( response ){
         //for debugging
     })

     .always( function( response ) {

     });
```

And the PHP script. Validations and other details are omitted, to be brief

```
if( isset( $_POST['submit_answer'] ) ){

     $question_number = $_POST['number'];

     $answer = $_POST['answer'];

     $assessment = new Assessment();

     if( $assessment->saveAnswer( array( 'number'=>$question_number, 'answer'=>$answer,) ){

        $response = 'OK';
     }
     else{

        $response = 'BAD';
    }
}
```

And the class that the above script instantiates:

```
class Assessment
{

    public function saveAnswer( array $answer )
    {
        $sql ="INSERT INTO table SET question_number = :number, answer = :answer;
        $stmt = $dbLink->prepare( $sql );

        $stmt->bindValue( ':number', $answer['number'], PDO::PARAM_STR );

        $stmt->bindValue( ':answer', $answer['answer'], PDO::PARAM_STR );

        $stmt->execute();

        if( $stmt->rowCount() == 1 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Now I am envisaging a scenario in which a user chooses their options and submits in very quick successions while the preceding submits have yet to be processed by the server. I tried this on development machine and found that some choices were missing from the database.

What could have caused this? Is it latency? How do I ensure that every choice is submitted irrespective of frequency of submission. What improvements or tweaks do I need to add on the server and client scripts or even on the db queries.

Comment: You can set that the user can go forward only after he choose something and after you got response from the ajax call.

Comment: Yes, or you can make the 'previous' and 'next' buttons part of a form containing a hidden question number and the radio buttons and post the values to the next page. No need for Ajax, no problems. Do not overcomplicate these simple things. (Ajax is nice though, if your users use the back and forward buttons of the browser, so stick with that.).

Comment: @Marco Mura,thanks. The problem with that solution is that the app is a time-bound assessment solution. If the user can only do next or back when they get response from ajax call, much time is wasted while waiting. Again, if they can only do next or back after they choose, then you take away the examination experience in which a candidate can flip to other questions if they discover a particular one is difficult.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, thanks also, I got the point. In that case the cumulative answers are submitted at some point later. However, I see another problem in that: the user will loose all work done if for any reason the browser or machine crashes or power failure or something. I considered all these before settling for my option. Well, maybe someone will show me a better option or improve those from Marco Mura and yours.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. First thanks to @KIKISoftware. I got an idea from his answer. Rather than post to the next page, In my javascript, I instantiated a global array variable thus:

```
var answers = [];
```

Then within the next and back button click events, I instantiated a local object variable thus:

```
var newAnswer = {
  number: questionNumber,
  answer: chosenAnswer 
};
```

This object is then added to the answers array. At intervals, say 60 secs, the array is posted to the server after using JSON.stringify( answer ).

This works like a charm. I am happy.